# React Native - How to implement a text editor natively

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to build a rich text editor with React Native, but I struggled to implement the inline tags, such as adding bold or italic styling to a word or a phrase just like in the picture

[image]
In web development this will be easily sorted out with a div with contenteditable set to true. Is there a way to do this with react native in a native way (no webview), or a workaround that could work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this package it gives you all the controls of rich text field
https://github.com/wxik/react-native-rich-editor

Comment: So it's not native